# Refactor passing params from a view to the controller in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So the below code is working, it passes the "experience" parameter to my controller.  My question revolves around finding a better way to pass the parameters for option1, option2, etc... when they are present.  I have a lot of scopes and the more scopes I add to filter the data the longer the filtered_jobs_path becomes.  I'm relatively new to rails so maybe this is the only way to do it but there seems like there should be a way to list all of the other filter options (option1, option2, etc...) somewhere and then call it in the view so each link_to isn't a mile long, is that possible?

```
<div class="well">
  <%= link_to "0-2 years", filtered_jobs_path(experience: '0-2 years', option1: params[:option1], option2: params[:option2]) %><br />
  <%= link_to "2-5 years", filtered_jobs_path(experience: '2-5 years', option1: params[:option1], option2: params[:option2]) %><br />
  <%= link_to "5-10 years", filtered_jobs_path(experience: '5-10 years', option1: params[:option1], option2: params[:option2]) %><br />
  <%= link_to "10+ years", filtered_jobs_path(experience: '10+ years', option1: params[:option1], option2: params[:option2]) %>        
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your filtered_jobs_path method?

Comment: if you use a helper method, `params` should be available there right? So you can make use of the received parameters there without having to pass them around, I think

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
# some_helper.rb
def filtered_jobs_link(text)
  link_to text, filtered_jobs_path(experience: text, option1: params[:option1], option2: params[:option2])
end


#some_view.html.erb
<div class="well">
  <%= filtered_jobs_link "0-2 years" %><br />
  <%= filtered_jobs_link "2-5 years" %><br />
  <%= filtered_jobs_link "5-10 years" %><br />
  <%= filtered_jobs_link "10+ years" %>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper:

```
module JobsHelper
  def filtered_jobs_link(text, **opts)
    opts.reverse_merge!(params.slice(:option1, :option2))
    link_to text, filtered_jobs_path(opts)
  end
end
```

And then iterate through the options:

```
<ul>
  <% ["0-2 years", "2-5 years", "5-10 years", "10+ years"].each do |o|%>
    <li><%= filtered_jobs_link(o, experience: o) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

If you really have to use that specific markup:

```
module JobsHelper
  def filtered_jobs_link(text, **opts)
    opts.reverse_merge!(params.slice(:option1, :option2))
    link_to text, filtered_jobs_path(opts)
  end

  def filtered_jobs_by_experience(*options)
    options.map { |o| filtered_jobs_link(o, experience: o) }.join('</ br>')
  end
end
```

---

```
<div class="well">
  <%= filtered_jobs_by_experience("0-2 years", "2-5 years", "5-10 years", "10+ years") %>
</div>
```